# Matplotlib ImageGrid colorbar not showing tick marks

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

This image shows the result of using `ImageGrid` to create an image with a colorbar:

[image]

The code is as follows.

```
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 211,
            nrows_ncols = (1, 1),
            axes_pad = 0.3,
            label_mode = "L",
            share_all = False,
            cbar_location="right",
            cbar_mode="single",
            cbar_size="7%",
            cbar_pad="7%",
            aspect = True
            )
```

and the colorbar is added by doing this:

```
cb = grid.cbar_axes.colorbar(im)
grid.cax.set_yticks([-14, -13, -12])
cb.set_label_text('$\log_{10}$(Intensity)')
```

However, the colorbar is missing the **tick marks** overlaid on the color scale.

So, my question is: how can I force the colorbar with the **tick marks** on top of the color scale?

**EDIT 2:** The blue arrows in [this new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JilAQ.png) indicate the result I would like to achieve. However, even in this new image, the tick marks seem to be 'behind' the color scale. I tried and played with `zorder` but couldn't bring the tick marks forward.

Comment: Could you try to make a complete, executable example?

Comment: Hi, roadrunner66! The full code has a lot of input data and modules created by me. Thus, I don't think it would be useful or executable for anyone else but me.

Comment: I understand but sometimes one can create a minimal example that still shows the problem at hand. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for inspiration. If others can't recreate the problem, it's very unlikely that they can help.

Answer (score 0):

searching i've found this

https://wcsaxes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ticks_labels_grid.html#coordinate-objects

I think that what you want is it:

https://wcsaxes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overlays.html

good luck dude :3, I'm sorry for not help but i dont understant about this content

Comment: Thanks, Milor123, but those links are not helpful (I have already checked them out, anyway). I want the tick marks, not the tick labels or title of the color bar.

Comment: can you show me a image ? i'm only a programmer i dont understand about it, but may be help you

Comment: Hi, Milor123! The image is linked to the "This image" sentence at the beginning of the post. Just click on it and you'll see the image.

Comment: dude could you copy all your code in pastebin ? i need somthing of your code

Comment: @mairan i've update the post, see the second link, i'm not sure but Hope this can help you

Comment: Hi, Milor123! Thanks again, but it's not about adding patches (that part I've already achieved). It's about the tick marks in the color bar. See the EDIT in my post. There a modified image showing what's missing in the color bar.

Comment: @mairan dude send me your complete code for i try run it and help you.